# GeoServer REST API update coverage

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

I have created a ECW coverage store and a coverage using the GeoServer REST API.
Initial I used the srs bounds for the coverage and the preview shows this (what I expected):

[image]

Now I want to update (PUT) the coverage and calculate the nativebbox & latlonbbox with this path/query:

https:// ... /geoserver/rest/workspaces/org1/coveragestores/Meerssen/coverages/meerssen_ecw?calculate=nativebbox,latlonbbox

Tested in Postman with no body (Content-Length=0 & no Content-Type), gives a 415 response code.

Why do I get the 415 Unsupported Media Type response?
Do I need to supply a body or Content-Type?

Answer (score 0):

GeoServer documentation is broken (I had the same error).

I sent a PUT request to `https:// ... /geoserver/rest/workspaces/{workspacesName}/coveragestores/{storeName}/coverages/{coverageName}` with body:

```
{
    "coverage": {
        "srs": "EPSG:4326"
    }
}
```

And a miracle happened !!!
Coverage successfully updated!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).